# A remarkable elimination involving the basic reproduction number R0

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I have a polynomial pol of third order, whose coefficients depend on 5 parameters, and whose free coefficient is proportional to R0-1, where R0 is a certain rational function of the  parameters (the basic reproduction number of unfortunate fame these days). It was stated without proof that pol=R0-Prod(1-i rk), where all rk are rational functions of the parameters.  I wonder if there is some general theory around this type of representation as a "rational  constant in the parameters + a rational factorization".

My polynomial is obtained  after elimination in a system in three variables (s,e,i)

```
sys = {\[CapitalLambda] - s (i \[Beta] + \[CapitalLambda]) + 
     i s \[Nu] == 0, 
   i s \[Beta] + e (-\[Gamma]e - \[CapitalLambda] + i \[Nu]) == 0, 
   e \[Gamma]e + i (-\[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] - \[Nu] + i \[Nu]) ==
     0};
el = Eliminate[sys, {s, e}]// FullSimplify
pol = Collect[el[[1]]/i - el[[2]]/i, i] // Simplify
fa=Factor[pol - pol[[1]]]
```

So, we have the representation  pol=pol[[1]]+fa

Note that the result el of 'Eliminate' above is quite ugly. Knowing that i is positive allows me to reduce its degree to 3 in pol. But  the miraculous factorization  of pol - pol[[1]]  above comes from a paper  (with no explanation), I couldn't have found it without knowing it already.
My  first question is if there exists  a systematic way, a  theory for finding  this type of "rational factorization plus constant" decompositions? However, I am unable to formulate my first question precisely, since clearly there are infinitely many such representations. The one I show here has some special significance, and the outstanding mystery is how come 'Eliminate' discovered the answer I wanted in the next program.
This is the next question. The most amazing thing is that first time when I programmed this, I `Eliminate` a harder system with 4 more parameters, and then particularized to the particular case. The   answer was then directly in the form I wanted "rational factorization plus constant". I include now the longer program.

```
s1 = \[CapitalLambda] - 
   s (\[Beta] i + \[Beta]e e + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]) + \
\[Gamma]r r + s \[Nu] i;
FM = {{\[Beta]e s + \[Nu] i, \[Beta] s}, {0, 
   0}}; VM = {{\[Gamma]e + \[CapitalLambda], 
   0}, {-ei, \[Nu] + \[Gamma] + \[CapitalLambda] - \[Nu] i}};
IM = (FM - VM).{e, i}; sys = {s1 == 0, IM[[1]] == 0, IM[[2]] == 0}

el = Eliminate[sys, {s, e}] // FullSimplify
elL = el /. {\[Beta]e -> 0, er -> 0, 
    ei -> \[Gamma]e, \[Gamma]r -> 0, \[Gamma]s -> 0} // FullSimplify
```

In this version, I did not need to tell Mathematica how to split pol before factoring (as in fa=Factor[pol - pol[[1]]]) the answer displayed is already in the "quasi-factored" form. Unfortunately, after I ``simplified" my program  to 5 parameters to present it on stackexchange, this luck disappeared, and I could not reproduce it.

Are there some `Simplify` type commands for coaxing `Eliminate` to get the answer in the form I want?

PS. In answer to Sayed, [Gamma]e is one parameter.

Comment: Running your code results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRilV.png), but try `sys = {\[CapitalLambda] - s (i \[Beta] + \[CapitalLambda]) + 
     i s \[Nu] == 0, 
   i s \[Beta] + e (-\[Gamma] e - \[CapitalLambda] + i \[Nu]) == 0, 
   e \[Gamma] e + 
     i (-\[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] - \[Nu] + i \[Nu]) == 0};` as there needs to be a space between `gamma` and `e`, I think.

Comment: What is the result you seek? I cannot tell from the post what exactly is the question.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. This is much more clear now.